# How do I enclose multiple Ruby on Rails database queries into an atomic statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm manipulating multiple Ruby on Rails database queries which include two different databases. I want them enclosed such that if one of the queries fails, all others must rollback. In short, I want to convert them into an atomic statement.

```
# a)
LocationRole.create!(
  role: new_params[:role],
  resource_type: 'Hub',
  resource_id: hub_data[:hub_id],
  user_id: new_params[:user_id]
)

# b)
LocationRole.create!(
  role: new_params[:role],
  resource_type: 'Cluster',
  resource_id: input[:cluster_id],
  user_id: new_params[:user_id]
)

# c)
User.create(:email=>email,:password=>password,:user_type=>user_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in a transaction:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  # a)
  # b)
  # c)
end
```

You might want to call `User.create!` (with bang) rather than `User.create` in order to raise an exception in case there's a validation error. Whenever an exception is raised inside a transaction, the transaction will be rolled back.